# Why Uri.fromFile() will not work on Android 7.0+, with a targetSdkVersion of 24 or higher. and what can be the alternate solution ? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, file-io, uri

android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///null exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

This is an error shown to me. What can be a proper alternative?

Answer (score 0):

--->This can be an alternative <----

Change:

**return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);**

to be:

**return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName()+".fileprovider", mediaFile);**